# What to type in redirect_to in nested attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

My question is how can i redirect to events show page after delete, create, update actions are done.

I am newbie in rails so please help me on this.I have routes file like this.

```
resources :occasions do
    resources :events
  end

  resources :events do
    resources :event_details
  end
```

My event_detail controller are:

```
before_action :set_event
  before_action :set_event_detail, except: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @event_detail = EventDetail.new
  end

  def create
    @event_detail = EventDetail.new(event_detail_params)
    @event_detail.event = @event

    @event_detail.save
    redirect_to
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    @event_detail.update(event_detail_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @event_detail.destroy
    redirect_to ??
  end


  private

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end

  def set_event_detail
    @event_detail = EventDetail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def event_detail_params
    params.require(:event_detail).permit(:capacity, :start_time, :end_time)
  end
```

Now, what i have is Occasion has many events as indicated on routes and events have many event_details. But, in my controller i do not have occasion, so i cannot route to http://localhost:3000/occasions/1/events/1 page after i delete or update my event_detail.

My rake routes file

```
  rake routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
         teacher_students GET    /teachers/:teacher_id/students(.:format)                                                 students#index
                          POST   /teachers/:teacher_id/students(.:format)                                                 students#create
      new_teacher_student GET    /teachers/:teacher_id/students/new(.:format)                                             students#new
     edit_teacher_student GET    /teachers/:teacher_id/students/:id/edit(.:format)                                        students#edit
          teacher_student GET    /teachers/:teacher_id/students/:id(.:format)                                             students#show
                          PATCH  /teachers/:teacher_id/students/:id(.:format)                                             students#update
                          PUT    /teachers/:teacher_id/students/:id(.:format)                                             students#update
                          DELETE /teachers/:teacher_id/students/:id(.:format)                                             students#destroy
                 teachers GET    /teachers(.:format)                                                                      teachers#index
                          POST   /teachers(.:format)                                                                      teachers#create
              new_teacher GET    /teachers/new(.:format)                                                                  teachers#new
             edit_teacher GET    /teachers/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             teachers#edit
                  teacher GET    /teachers/:id(.:format)                                                                  teachers#show
                          PATCH  /teachers/:id(.:format)                                                                  teachers#update
                          PUT    /teachers/:id(.:format)                                                                  teachers#update
                          DELETE /teachers/:id(.:format)                                                                  teachers#destroy
          occasion_events GET    /occasions/:occasion_id/events(.:format)                                                 events#index
                          POST   /occasions/:occasion_id/events(.:format)                                                 events#create
       new_occasion_event GET    /occasions/:occasion_id/events/new(.:format)                                             events#new
      edit_occasion_event GET    /occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id/edit(.:format)                                        events#edit
           occasion_event GET    /occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id(.:format)                                             events#show
                          PATCH  /occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id(.:format)                                             events#update
                          PUT    /occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id(.:format)                                             events#update
                          DELETE /occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id(.:format)                                             events#destroy
                occasions GET    /occasions(.:format)                                                                     occasions#index
                          POST   /occasions(.:format)                                                                     occasions#create
             new_occasion GET    /occasions/new(.:format)                                                                 occasions#new
            edit_occasion GET    /occasions/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            occasions#edit
                 occasion GET    /occasions/:id(.:format)                                                                 occasions#show
                          PATCH  /occasions/:id(.:format)                                                                 occasions#update
                          PUT    /occasions/:id(.:format)                                                                 occasions#update
                          DELETE /occasions/:id(.:format)                                                                 occasions#destroy
      event_event_details GET    /events/:event_id/event_details(.:format)                                                event_details#index
                          POST   /events/:event_id/event_details(.:format)                                                event_details#create
   new_event_event_detail GET    /events/:event_id/event_details/new(.:format)                                            event_details#new
  edit_event_event_detail GET    /events/:event_id/event_details/:id/edit(.:format)                                       event_details#edit
       event_event_detail GET    /events/:event_id/event_details/:id(.:format)                                            event_details#show
                          PATCH  /events/:event_id/event_details/:id(.:format)                                            event_details#update
                          PUT    /events/:event_id/event_details/:id(.:format)                                            event_details#update
                          DELETE /events/:event_id/event_details/:id(.:format)                                            event_details#destroy
                   events GET    /events(.:format)                                                                        events#index
                          POST   /events(.:format)                                                                        events#create
                new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                                                                    events#new
               edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               events#edit
                    event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#show
                          PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#update
                          PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#update
                          DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#destroy
                     root GET    /                                                                                        homeroutes#routes
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

My event controller

```
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_occasion, expect: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_event, except: [:new, :create]
  # after_action :verify_authorized

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    # authorize @event
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.occasion = @occasion
    # authorize @event
    @event.save
    redirect_to occasion_path(@occasion)
  end

  def edit
  # authorize @event
  end

  def show
    # authorize @event
  end

  def update
    # authorize @event
    @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to occasion_path(@occasion)
  end

  def destroy
    # authorize @event
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to occasion_path(@occasion)
  end

  private

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_occasion
    @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:occasion_id])
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :description, :isMakeAhead)
  end
end
```

And my view file in event#show page:

```
<h1>Event Info</h1>


<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Make ahead</td>
    <td>Capacity</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @event.name %></td>
    <td><%= @event.location %></td>
    <td><%= @event.description %></td>
    <td><%= @event.isMakeAhead %></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= render @event.event_details %>
<p><%= link_to "Create Time slots", new_event_event_detail_path(@event,@event_detail) %></p>
```

I can create an event_detail but i have to refresh the page and go to http://localhost:3000/occasions/1/events/1 manually to see the new creation. Is there any way after creation of event_detail, i can redirect back to this "http://localhost:3000/occasions/1/events/1" page. Any help will be kindly appreciated.

The error i am getting: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXi4N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove :index and :show from except in your route definition then after create/update, try:

```
redirect_to event_event_detail_path(@event_detail)
```

After destroy there won't be an @event_detail to redirect_to so you probably want to:

```
redirect_to event_details_path
```

Also

```
rake routes | grep event
```

... will show you your application routes, and [the Rails routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) brings light into such dark moments

`redirect_to` takes a path parameter, for instance `occasions_path` to redirec to the occasions index action, or `event_event_detail_path(@event_detail) to redirect to the @event_detail show action. You can use redirect_to to tell the client (browser) to go to any part of the application laid out in your routes, or even relative or absolute URLs. Later on you will learn you can also add all kinds of parameters and HTTP status codes.

Comment: The error after i put your code is undefined method `event_detail_path' for #<EventDetailsController:0x000000000c364320>
Did you mean?  event_detail_params


  def create
    @event_detail = EventDetail.new(event_detail_params)
    @event_detail.event = @event
    @event_detail.save
    redirect_to event_detail_path(@event_detail)
  end

Comment: Right, it's namespaced... remove the :show from the exception in your route definition then run rake routes again, it will show you the paths.

Comment: Also the rails routing guide will help you understand many things and will give you a fresh perspective on laying out your app structure.

Comment: Thank you FU, much appreciated sir, gotta start thinking my comments more before posting!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after following all the suggestion you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Please post another `rake routes` output after updating routes.rb

Comment: I actually just want to go redirect_back but in Rails 5 this command is already removed. Also, i want to get to this occasion_event_path "/occasions/:occasion_id/events/:id(.:format)", but i as i mentioned i don't have any occasion on event_details controller so i cannot redirect it to there.

Comment: If you want to redirect "back" to occasions you can just  do a `redirect_to occasions_path`. You see the pattern here: `redirect_to` plus whatever `rake routes` tells you, with any parameters if required.

Comment: Correct. I can do that but i want to redirect_to occasion>event#show page. That's where i'm getting the error.

Comment: I cannot go to occasion because my event_details controller does not have @occasion. So i cannot type in redirect_to occasion_event_path(@occasion, @event) right? As occasion is not present inside the event_path controller, occasion_id will be null.

Comment: You have an EventPath controller?

Comment: Yes i do. I'll post my event controller above.

Comment: Well, EventsController is not the same thing as EventPathController which I suspect you don't have. event_path(@event) is the Rails routing helper for the :show action within EventsController with an @event as parameter. I'd  suggest reading the Rails routing guide, I know it's annoying being told to RT...M believe me I know how you feel, in this case however it will save you a lot of time and headache and once you understand how it works you'll be happy you read it. I've added a link above. Here's the path helpers section: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will read and try to find ways as you suggested and mark your answer correct.

Comment: Enjoy Rails Zaa! It’s very powerful, just taking a bit to get a grip on but IMO very much worth it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to change your routes.

```
resources :occasions do
    resources :events do
      resources :event_details
    end
end
```

Then you can post your rake routes and based on the route for occasion index or event index can route.

Comment: But rails documentation says do not deep nest more than one resource. Is this a good options?

Comment: Akhil is right It can work! go on and do it and run `rake routes` again to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
redirect_to event_path(@event)
```

Comment: Pandey ji, it to go to event, i will need a occasion id. So as i mentioned my resources don't include occasion. So redirecting to event path searches for occasion id first and then event id which i don't have with my current routes. Jay Nepal.

Comment: `event GET    /events/:id(.:format)`  I doubt you need occasion id for this? Where do you want to go? inside the event of occassion?

Comment: What i have is occasion has many events. And events have many occasions. So, while going on show page of occasion, there are lists of events. Now, under the show page of each events there are many event_details(time slots etc). So, now after i create a event_details, i want to go to the event_show page which nests inside a occasion. So redirect_to event_path(@event) will try to find occasion,which is not available when in event_details controller. Hajur le malai tutor garney ho bhane ma paisa tirera padhna tayar chu.

Comment: Sure i can guide you based on what you are refering your routes should be `resources :occasions do  resources :events do  resources :event_details end end end` I need to see the views but i need the refrence to all code for that to solve this could you give the code link so that it will be easy.

Comment: here is my email ynique.adhar@gmail.com